# Who was Lord Commander of the Night's Watch at the end of the show?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Edd appears to be leading the Watch early in S8 (though seemingly appointed by Jon rather than elected).

> He clearly can't be by the end as he's killed at Winterfell.

**We know the Watch still exists at the end, but who's in charge?**

We can't rule out Jon from what I've seen -

> he's returned to them - but there's nothing to suggest he returns into a position of authority or is immediately elected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As is, unfortunately, the motto of season 8...

#### [We Do Not <s>Sow</s> Know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd0V5.jpg)

We can, however, rule out Jon as at the end of the final episode he leaves Castle Black and the Seven Kingdoms to go live in the North with the Free Folk.

Of the only other members we know of there is Samwell Tarly, who is now the Grand Maester and so would not be Lord Commander and also doesn't appear to be a member of the Night's Watch at all anymore.

As far as I'm aware all of the other known members are dead and so we don't have a known named character that could be the new Lord Commander. In fact considering the events of the final season there might not even be a new Lord Commander yet.

Comment: The Night King's gone! The Wall isn't needed any more! Let it melt!

Comment: It wasn't clear to me whether Jon was heading North permanently or merely escorting his friends, but I may have missed a line or a visual cue.  The loose ends were tied up rather rapidly

Comment: @PaulD.Waite and the Wildlings are everyone's friends.  For now.  But there's still a watch

Comment: @ChrisH You'll get used to Paul, he hardly ever says anything seriously... As for your first comment, Jon turns back to look at the Wall with a melancholic look suggesting he is leaving it all behind.